# Xpage - combo box disappears

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have a strange error

I created 2 combo boxes

the first (cadcri_est) does a search and loads the list of states from an nsf base, like the code below.

The second combo box (cadcri_cid), reads the first and does another search, bringing the list of cities.

in "values" of cadcri_cid I have
1st do

```
return "";
```

2nd after

```
var dbname1 = session.getServerName() + "!!" + "estmun.nsf";
var categoryComp = getComponent("cadcri_est");
if ((categoryComp) == null) return "";
var category = categoryComp.getValue();
if (category == "") return "";
var res = @Unique(@DbLookup(dbname1, "vestmun", category, 2));
document1.replaceItemValue("cadcri_cid", "");
return res;
```

And in the onchange event of the 1st combo box, I do a Partial Update on cadcri_cid

The problem happens if the user selects the state, the city and then tries to change the state again.
in this case, the second combo box disappears and only comes back with an update on the page.
If he first clears the selected city (the first item in the list is ""), then he can change the state and the list of cities loads normally.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

I tried loading "" (blank) into the values ​​of the cadcri_cid combo, before reloading the list of cities (apparently this works when done manually), but it didn't work.

Comment: I found that the error happens when the option:

"Next page (if update fails):"

this with any option other than "Same Page".

Is there something wrong with the code that fetches the values?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code:

- Try to avoid looking up the components. Always use data binding. Either to a document or a scope variable.
- Don’t return „“ as value when the category isn’t selected, but something like „- Select region first-„

Let us know how it goes